# ¿Por qué este archivo de login ignora la contraseña?

Tags: php, pdo, login

El problema es que no verifica que la contraseña este correcta, solo con el nombre de usuario, y aun no se por qué.

### El código:

```
    session_start();

$data = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

try {

    require 'connexion.php';

    $log = $con->prepare("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE (user = :user OR email = :email) AND password = :password");
    $log->bindParam(':user', $data);
    $log->bindParam(':email', $data);
    $log->bindParam(':password', $pass);

    $log->execute();

    $count = $log->rowCount();
    $dt = $log->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

    $con = null;

    if ($count == 1){

        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $dt->ID;
        header('Location: http://***.***/index.php');

    } else {

        echo "Fail Epic";

    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    die("Epic Fail: " . $e->getMessage());

}
```

> P.1: Las claves de inicio de un archivo php () si están
>   incluidas en el archivo original.
>
> P.2: Los * son para poner a modo de
>   ejemplo no de página real.

Comment: Te hace falta recibir el parametro email enviado por POST

Comment: Le estás pasando el valor de user en el `email`, no es la misma cosa, supongo. Recoges esto: `$data = $_POST['user'];` y luego pasas esto: `$log->bindParam(':email', $data);`.  En el código no se ve dónde recibes el valor del `email` con el cual quieres comparar.

Comment: Ya lo recibe, en el post de data (1 línea) recibe el usuario o email, por eso abajo se usa la misma variable (líneas 9 y 10)

Comment: Entonces tienes que probar la consulta en tu base de datos, puede que los datos no existan con ese criterio. O que se estén escribiendo con espacios en blanco o algo así. ¿Estás limpiando tus datos con funciones como `trim`?

Comment: No; los datos si existen en la base de datos.

Comment: Podrias mostra la informacion de tu tabla users?

Comment: si los datos existen eso significa que esta haciendo la consulta bien verdad? si esta haciendo bien la consulta (no da ningún error de sintaxis)  eso quiere decir que si colocas usuario y contraseña (como doble llave primaria de validacion) debiese funcionar es decir si user y pass correspnden devuelve datos, de no ser asi devuelve null.  ahora a que te refieres que no este validando que la contraseña este correcta? aunque el user y la pass no coincidan con las columnas en la tabla igual devuelve datos?

Comment: Fenix, me parece que esta línea: `$dt = $log->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` te crea en realidad **un array de objetos**. Puedes verificarlo haciendo esto: `var_dump($dt);`.  Si es como digo, entonces debes hacer la comparación así: **`$_SESSION["user_id"] = $dt[0]->ID;`** En cualquier caso, muéstranos el `var_dump($dt);` para salir de dudas sobre lo que ocurre con tu consulta realmente.

Comment: También convendría depurar  la variable `$count` con un `var_dump($count);` ya que si no es igual a `1` (supongamos que haya más de un registro con los mismos criterios), no entraría.

Comment: No será que te devuelve el nombre de la columna en minúscula, y tengas que accederla con `$dt->id`?